# Is Hot-Deploy of JSP files with Jetty Maven Plugin (from within Eclipse) using Maven's WAR-Overlays possible without restarting Jetty?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, maven-jetty-plugin, maven-war-plugin

Hello I'm using the maven-jetty-plugin (v 9.4.7.v20170914) from within Eclipse (mvn jetty:run) and changes to JSP files where reflected immediately without the necessity of restarting Jetty (scanIntervalSeconds=0) before I was using the Maven WAR-Overlay feature.

After changigng the project to a Multimodule layout and using Mavens WAR-Overlay feature changes in JSP-Files are only reflected when restarting Jetty.

**My question is:** Is it possible in general to immediately reflect JSP-Changes using the Jetty-Maven-Plugin and Maven WAR-Overlays without the need of restarting Jetty?

I'm looking around for a few hours now and tried loads of things. I'm not sure if I should spend more time investigating this issue if it is simply not possible...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use `mvnDebug jetty:run` to run you app, as this is in debug mode, so you can compile your jsp file( as eclipse will automatic compile your file so you just need save it )

and suggest you to use the dcevm plugin for hotswapping.

Comment: When running `mvnDebug jetty:run` I only get these two lines: `Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug Mode` and `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000` but the jetty doesn't start. Are you sure this helps? As I mentioned it worked when using a single Maven-Module and running `jetty:run` with an Eclipse Debug Configuration. It just doesn't work anymore when using WAR-Overlays.

Comment: Yep, this will listening the debug port, then you need using run IDE(eclipse) remote debug

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the way using `mvnDebug` doesn't help with my JSP-Problem when using WAR-Overlays. It's the same as using a Maven-Run-Configuration from within Eclipse. I'm using the "Eclipse FileSync Plugin" now to copy the changed JSP's. Thanks for the tip with the DCEVM! This works like a glance!